# Enabling / Disabling checkboxes on single checkbox click using JQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm new to JQuery and struggling to fix a problem in which I'm trying to disable a number of checkboxes when one Main checkbox is checked.

I have a form which contains 1 primary checkbox and 3 secondary checkboxes.  When the primary checkbox is checked, all the other secondary checkboxes are disabled but must have a checked status by default.  And when the primary checkbox is unchecked then all the other secondary checkboxes which were disabled turn to enabled and must all be checked.  By default, when a user arrives on the form: the primary checkbox must be checked and thus, the other 3 must be checked and disabled.

this is my code:

```
<s:checkbox id="primary_CB" name="primaryCB" value="true"/>Primary checkbox
<s:checkbox cssClass="secondary_CB" name="secondary_CB1"/>Secondary checkbox1
<s:checkbox cssClass="secondary_CB" name="secondary_CB2"/>Secondary checkbox2
<s:checkbox cssClass="secondary_CB" name="secondary_CB3"/>Secondary checkbox3
```

my JQuery code:

```
$('#primary_CB').click(function () {
if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
$(".secondary_CB").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {
    $(".secondary_CB").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

however my code works in strange way, when I'm on the form for the first time, all 4 checkboxes are checked, none disabled.  Only when I uncheck/check again the primary checkbox that the disable function takes place.  Also, when disable again all secondary checkboxes go unchecked automatically.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, if I understand your problem correctly:

```
$("#primary_CB").click(function() {
    $("input.secondary_CB").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

for jQuery below 1.6

```
$("#primary_CB").click(function() {
    $("input.secondary_CB").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Or you can get rid of the if/else and just do  `$("input.secondary_CB").prop("disabled", !this.checked);`

Comment: @wirey Oh devil you. Of course, sometimes you try to answer way to quickly :) Updated and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: just tried it, but it looks like I have a problem using prop() method.  I'm using jquery-1.3.2.

Comment: @user1353307 Then you have to use .attr(), if you can't update to jQuery 1.6+.

Comment: @user1353307 use attr instead of prop then.. so for this line of code just replace prop with attr

Comment: worked with attr().  I also had to add disabled="true" AND value="true" in the secondary checkboxes tags.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#primary_CB').click(function () {
if ( !$(this).is ( ":checked" ) )
{
$(".secondary_CB").attr ( "disabled" , true );
} else {
    $(".secondary_CB").removeAttr ( "disabled" );
    }
});
```

Comment: You should use `.prop()` instead of `attr` for this. We want to change the property, not the attribute.

Comment: it looks like.prop() doesn't works at all.  I'm using jquery-1.3.2, when I use .attr() the code above works just like I described above (not as I wish), when I replace it with .prop() nothing happens, as if the code wasn't there. can it be because my JQuery version doesn't include prop method?